# Why can i not recall an element from a list gotten from a separated string?

Tags: python, api

```
    import requests
    import time
    response = requests.get('https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/London?unitGroup=metric&elements=temp%2Cwindspeed%2Csunrise%2Csunset%2Cmoonphase&key=(Not sharing my API key)&contentType=json')
    response = str(response)
    print(len(response))
    response = response.split(",")
    print(response[1])
```

What can i do to solve this?
I know that it became a list, as now it has a lengh of 16, but why can i not call elements from that list?

Comment: `response` isn't a list.

Comment: you could use the JSON library to read in the  request into a dictionary like object

Comment: to access the real response you should go response = response.json()

Comment: You probably already got the answer but generally you should be more precise than "I cannot". What happens, what should happen?

Comment: `str(response)` gives you the (rather useless) string representation of the response, _not_ the actual content. For this, try `response.text` or `response.json()`, depending on what the API returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead access the value of response on line 4 with:

`response = response.json()`

response will then be a dictionary representing a dictionary of the json returned from the request

Answer (score 0):

The variable `response` you get is a `string` with 16 characters in it; none of them is a comma (the string reads: "<Response [401]>"). That means that after your `.split()` with a comma as separator, you have a list with one element in it, so your indexation with `[1]` is out of bounds.

Comment: `response` itself is _not_ a `str`, but OP converts it to one, instead of using it's `text` or `json()`. Also, it's oly 401 because of the missing API key. Otherwise, yes, this correctly explains the error, but not how to fix it.